# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fbconnect

Because my app depends much on Network, I wish my app should not hang up.
So i tried to use Asyncask

I have a

1. MainActvity extends Second Activity
2. AsyncTask as Inner Class in MainActivity
3. Second Activity

**Main Activity and Async Task :**

```
public class MainActivity extends secondActivity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    new triggerAsync().execute(str);
}

private class triggerAsync extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override       
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

        try {
             setConnection();
             getID(txtUserName);
             Log.d("Inside Background","string here"+str[0]);
            // postOnWall(str[0]);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }}}
```

**Second Activity :**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {


public void setConnection() {
    //My stuffs
}

public void getID(TextView txtUserName) {

    // here i'm calling another function inside package

    if (isSession()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
    } else {
        // no logged in, so relogin
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
    } 
}

/////////////// Code continues.....}
```

What is the error in this code, please help me to solve this
I'm getting below error

```
08-15 11:01:07.211: WARN/System.err(462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-15 11:01:07.251: WARN/System.err(462):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-15 11:01:07.251: WARN/System.err(462):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
08-15 11:01:07.271: WARN/System.err(462):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:123)
08-15 11:01:07.271: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog.<init>(FbDialog.java:63)
08-15 11:01:07.281: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.dialog(Facebook.java:622)
08-15 11:01:07.291: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.startDialogAuth(Facebook.java:297)
08-15 11:01:07.301: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:195)
08-15 11:01:07.311: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.authorize(Facebook.java:114)
08-15 11:01:07.321: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.singleupdater.FacebookActivity.getID(FacebookActivity.java:61)
08-15 11:01:07.331: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.singleupdater.SingleStausUpdater$postToTwitter.doInBackground(SingleStausUpdater.java:149)
08-15 11:01:07.341: WARN/System.err(462):     at com.singleupdater.SingleStausUpdater$postToTwitter.doInBackground(SingleStausUpdater.java:1)
08-15 11:01:07.351: WARN/System.err(462):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-15 11:01:07.361: WARN/System.err(462):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-15 11:01:07.371: WARN/System.err(462):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-15 11:01:07.371: WARN/System.err(462):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
08-15 11:01:07.391: WARN/System.err(462):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
08-15 11:01:07.391: WARN/System.err(462):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of your methods - `setConnection()` or `getID(txtUserName)` tries to access UI from background thread and fails. Move your UI logic to `onPostExecute` to be processed on UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply ernazm. If i call in onPreExecute()/ onPostExecute method will this be executed in separate thread or it will be in UI thread?

Comment: These 2 methods will be executed in UI thread, so you will only apply the results of your work there (like setting `TextView`s etc). All your heavy-weight work like web service communication and calculations should be still performed in `doInBackground` since it's the background thread that won't cause UI to be frozen.

Comment: ya i got it. so u mean to say i have to bring all calculations in second activity inside Async task right?

Comment: inside `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` to be precise